# Angularjs - How to import Bootstrap into Karma-Jasmine for testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that call a method from bootstrap.min.js and when I write a test file to test it it render the error say that the function I used is not defined. I think the reason which cause this error is because I didn't include Bootstrap in test enviroment.I searched many times on Google but have not find a way to get Bootstrap work with Karma-Jasmine. Does any know a way how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the `files` to your `karma.conf.js` it should work.
Example is from [here](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/08/05/angular-4-karma-loading-css-in-unit-testing/).

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    singleRun: false,
    files: [
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css",
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    ]
  });
};
```

If you use Bower or some other package manager just change the path e.g.

```
"bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
```

Pay attention to have the right relative path to your file. Maybe you need to add or omit `../` at the beginning

Comment: Thanks, I always end up banging my head against the wall with Karma, this helped.